# Tableau Calculated field (can't mix aggregate - non aggregate functions)

Tags: sql, tableau-api, calculated-field

*Promo on This Sku* contains an aggregate of promos applicable on the Skus and I was using this below code for calculated field to find Promo Net Sales wherever the my Promo ID (*Sls Prmo ID*) has been applied. But it says an error "can't mix aggregate and non-aggregate arguments with this function"

Example *Promo on This Sku*: p1,p2,p3 and I want p3 sales only so my *Sls promo id* would be p3 here

Code:

IF CONTAINS([Promos On This Sku],ATTR(STR([Sls Prmo Id]))) then STR(SUM([Promo Net Sls]))
ELSE STR(0)
END

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the formula behind [Promos On This Sku], which could make my suggestion a non-starter, you can try altering your formula to:

SUM(IF CONTAINS([Promos On This Sku],[Sls Prmo Id]) then [Promo Net Sls] END)

You could wrap that in STR if it's important to return this as a string